# Fetch response from TNetHttpClient of MimeType application/pdf

Tags: delphi, rad

I am calling an API in Delphi the response of which is a pdf file. I am getting IHttpResponse, with MimeType application-pdf. How can I create a pdf file from this response?

Code:

```
response := Form1.NetHTTPClient1.Post(apiurl,parametres, nil, headerparams);
responsestring := response.ContentAsString(tencoding.UTF8);
Form1.memo.Lines.Add(responsestring);
```

When I try to convert the response to `ContentAsString` the below error is coming:

[image]

I even tried to pass a TStream Object in the post request:

```
response := Form1.NetHTTPClient1.Post(apiurl,parametres, resStream, headerparams);
responsestring := response.ContentAsString(tencoding.UTF8);
Form1.memo.Lines.Add(responsestring);
```

But the value of resStream is '' after Post call. The response code is coming 200 which means I am getting a response.

In Postman when I try this, I get a pdf file in response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't treat a binary PDF file as a UTF-8 string, which is why `ContentAsString()` is failing with an encoding error.

Per the [`TNetHttpClient.Post()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPClient.Post) documentation:

> If you want to receive the response data as your HTTP client downloads it from the target server, instead of waiting for your HTTP client to download the whole data, use the `AResponseContent` parameter to specify a [stream](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStream) to receive the downloaded data. Alternatively, you can wait for your HTTP client to download the whole response data, and obtain the response data as a stream from the [`ContentStream`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.URLClient.IURLResponse.ContentStream) property of the [response object](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClient.IHTTPResponse) that [`Post`] returns.

So, either of these approaches should work fine:

```pascal
response := Form1.NetHTTPClient1.Post(apiurl, parametres, nil, headerparams);
fs := TFileStream.Create('path\output.pdf', fmCreate);
try
  fs.CopyFrom(response.ContentStream, 0);
finally
  fs.Free;
end;
```

```pascal
fs := TFileStream.Create('path\output.pdf', fmCreate);
try
  Form1.NetHTTPClient1.Post(apiurl, parametres, fs, headerparams);
finally
  fs.Free;
end;
```

If they do not work for you, you will need to [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero.